# Passing CommandArguement to LinkButton from variable

Tags: asp.net, webforms, commandargument

I have seen many resources on SO that say that I can use following syntax to pass value to CommandArguement of `LinkButton'

```
<%forearch(var comment in Comments){%>
<asp:LinkButton ID="del" CommandArguement='<%= comment.CommentId%>' onCommand="delete_click" Text="Delete"/>

<%}%>
```

But when I write this in my ascx file and click on the link the value passed to command argument is `"<%=comment.CommentId%>"` instead of commentId itself. Please guide what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**
based on answers and comments, I have moved to use repeater instead of foreach and plain code. Here is the code I have come up with

```
<asp:Repeater ID="commRepeater" SelectMethod="GetPageComments" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>
                <%#Eval("Comment") %> 
                <%if(Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Page.User.Identity.GetUserId() == Eval("UserId")){ %>
                <span>
                    <asp:LinkButton  Text="Edit" runat="server" ID="EditLink" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CommentId")%>' OnClick="Update_Comment" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton  Text="Delete" runat="server" ID="DeleteLink" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CommentId")%>' OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;" OnCommand="Delete_Comment"  />
                </span>
                <%} %>

            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>        </asp:Repeater>
```

you can see that I am trying to show the edit and delete links if user is logged in and his Id matches with user who commented but it tells me that I can on use `Eval` in databound controls. how would I hide/show edit/delete links conditionally within repeater

Comment: please note that I have used single quotation with `'<%=comment.CommentId%>'` when passing to command argument

Comment: It should be `CommandArgument` BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use codebehind, for example in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        del.CommandArgument = comment.CommentId;
    }
}
```

Maybe a better approach would be to use the `Comments`-collection(which seems to be a list or array of a custom class) as `DataSource` of a `Repeater`(or other web-databound control). Then you can add the `LinkButtons` to the `Itemtemplate`.

You can then either use `ItemCreated` or `ItemDataBound` events of the repeater in codebehind or inline ASP.NET tags to bind the `CommandArgument`.

For example:

```
CommandArguement='<%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "CommentId" ) %>'
```

Comment: there are multiple LinkButtons created in a loop how can i set command argument for each in code behind?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: is that ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: but `<%forearch` is not valid ASP.NET syntax. So how and where did you actually create these controls? You know that you also could use `Comments` as datasource for a repeater and add the `LinkButtons` to the `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: can you point me to an example of repeater with `IEnumerable` plz?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: just make the `Comments`(which seems to be a list or array of a custom class)  the `DataSource` of the repeater and `DataBind` it. You can then either use `ItemCreated` or `ItemDataBound` events of the repeater in codebehind or inline ASP.NET tags to bind the `CommandArgument`. For example: `CommandArguement='<%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "CommentId" ) %>'`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing currently is not recommended and is highly error prone. You can easily achieve this with ASP.NET Repeater control like this:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="del" CommandArguement='<%# Eval("CommentId") %>' 
                 OnCommand="del_Command" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In Page_Load simply bind it:-

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
      MyRepeater.DataSource = CommentsRepository();
      MyRepeater.DataBind();
 }
```

Or Else if you are have ASP.NET 4.5 then use strongly type Data Bound controls like this:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="MyNamespace.Comment" 
              SelectMethod="MyRepeater_GetData">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="del" CommandArguement='<%# Item.CommentId %>'
                    OnCommand="del_Command" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And you method in code behind should be something like this(just for Demo):-

```
public IEnumerable<MyNamespace.Comment> MyRepeater_GetData()
{
   return new List<Comment>
   {
       new Comment { CommentId =1, Name= "foo"},
       new Comment { CommentId =2, Name= "bar"},
   };
}
```